# Can't edit EditText in Popup Activity

Tags: android, android-edittext, popup

I am using Popup Activity (which is an Activity that extends Activity with **android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog"**) . It contains Edit text but it's not editable .

All the similar question are about popup windows not popup activity and they don't work here

This is the **activity**:

```
public class BugActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_bug);
        EditText title = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bug_subject);
        title.setFocusable(true);
        title.setText("");
        EditText content = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.bug_content);
        DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
        getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
        int wi = dm.widthPixels;
        int hi = dm.heightPixels;
        getWindow().setLayout((int) (wi * .84), (int) (hi * .8));
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttachedToWindow() {
        super.onAttachedToWindow();

        View view = getWindow().getDecorView();
        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = (WindowManager.LayoutParams) view.getLayoutParams();
        lp.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.TOP;
        lp.y = 10;

        getWindowManager().updateViewLayout(view, lp);
    }
}
```

This is the **layout**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:id="@+id/activity_bug"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="zxc.laitooo.mangareader.BugActivity">



    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:textColor="@color/manga_white"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:id="@+id/bug_subject"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bug_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="17dp">

        <requestFocus/>
    </EditText>


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textColor="@color/manga_bug_text"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:text="@string/message"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="16dp"/>

    <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:textColor="@color/manga_white"
        android:inputType="text"
        android:gravity="start"
        android:id="@+id/bug_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_bug_content"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:textSize="17dp">

        <requestFocus/>

    </EditText>

</LinearLayout>
```

I tried using **requestFocus** and **setFocusable()** but still doesn't work